# Copy a linked list to another linked list c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to copy 1 list to another, but it copies only the first element. When I debug it, it showed me the error on the highlighted line.
Can you help me to solve this error and explain to me what's going wrong?

```
struct List1 {
    int data;
    List* next;
};

struct List3 {
    int data3;
    List3* next3;
};

void copyList(){
    if(p==NULL) cout<<"Lista este vida\n";
    else
    {
        c=p;
        List3* x = new List3;
        while(c!=NULL)
        {
            ***x->data3 = c->data;***
            cout<<x->data3<<" ";
            c=c->next;
            x=x->next3;
        }
    }
    cout <<"\nList has been copied successful\n";
}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code in a debugger to see what's going on? What is `p`? The indentation here is also a bit wrecked, so it's worth fixing that to better clarify what's going on.

Comment: two structs you have?

Comment: When do you update `x->next3`?

Comment: Your problem is not the line you indicated. It's because you are not allocating new nodes for the new list.

Comment: Both list structures are ding the same thing and look a lot more like they should be `node` or `link` as opposed to `list` since they represent only a single piece of a list. I see no assurances that the `next` pointers are being set to anything useful, so `x=x->next3;` is doomed to an ill fate.

Comment: It seems odd to have two incompatible data structures with identical internals as well.

Comment: This code looks like you're just slapping code into a computer without really thinking about it or having any sort of a plan. I recommend a sit-down far away from the computer with a pencil and paper while you figure out what it is you really want to do. Draw pictures. One of the best ways to figure out linked lists is to visualize the list. Draw pictures of how they have to link.

Comment: I agree. With linked lists paper and pencil diagrams are great to understand what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are allocating only 1 `List3` node for your `x` list.

On the first loop iteration, `x` points to a valid `List3` instance.  But you are not initializing its `next3` member.  So on the next loop iteration, the value of `x` becomes *indeterminate*, it is not pointing at valid memory.

You need to allocate a separate node for *every* value that you want to copy.  For example:

```
void copyList()
{
    if (p == NULL)
        cout << "Lista este vida\n";
    else
    {
        List1 *c = p;
        List3* x = NULL;
        List3** px = &x;

        do
        {
            *px = new List3;
            (*px)->data3 = c->data;
            (*px)->next3 = NULL;

            cout << (*px)->data3 << " ";

            px = &((*px)->next3);
            c = c->next;
        }
        while (c != NULL);

        // use x as needed. don't forget to delete all
        // of the nodes when you are done using them!

        cout << "\nList has been copied successful\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, but is it possible to delete also in this procedure the original list?

Comment: @Alex of course, you can do that inside your loop, simply `delete` the `c` node before moving on to the next node. But why do you need to copy and delete the original list at all? It would be easier to just transfer ownership of the original list and not make a copy at all.

Comment: hm, I'm trying to remove the whole list, but I don't what do you mean to transfer. I've actually tried to use `delete` but when I call the print function again, it prints me the same list. Can you give me a hint or what actually do I have to change in this code?

Comment: @Alex Read up about "move semantics". But this code can't transfer ownership of memory since you are using different types `List1` and `List3`. But they have the same data, so you should merge them into one type instead. Then you can simply do `x = p; p = NULL;` to transfer ownership

Comment: @Alex As for deleting nodes, inside the loop, you can do the following at the end of each iteration: `List1 *n = c; delete c; c = n;` Don't forget to reset `p` to NULL before exiting. I would use `List1 **c = &p;` instead and replace `c` with `*c` everywhere, so that `*c = n;` will NULL out `p` when the last node is `delete`'ed. But really, a function named `copyList()` shouldn't be deleting anything. You should have a separate `deleteList()` function for that. Your functions should be simply and concise, don't make them overly complicated. That will help you write code you can easily manage